# any software to receive sounds uninteruptly from remote PC

Tags: audio, remote-desktop, skype

I have used team Viewer but the problem is when I access remote PC it uses more processing for desktop sharing. in the process it occupies more than 10-30% of processing. But enabling the call feature the cpu usage differs a little. But I like the audio quality and uninterrupted ability of teamviewer very much. I need a dedicated software for just for the audio and will take less cpu load and should be uninterrupted and quality.

I will not use skype, it's ....... I don't like.

thanks

Comment: Actually with my connection skype interrupts a lot.

Comment: It's not what you asked for, but We use an old iPod touch with a free app from the app store.  We can watch and/or listen via PC or iPhone, locally or remotely. Don't know if it's uninterruptible, but the connection never drops.  I don't endorse specific apps but it's really easy to find with an app store search.